# Why is Visual Studio 2010 loading 40megs every second for a few minutes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a large solution, contains about 10 web references, open in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 64bit with 16G ram. One or more a day, Visual Studio stalls and hangs for about 3-5 minutes. Looking at the task manager, I can see that it's doing about 40megs of I/O reads every second. This goes on for a few minutes while VS is unusable. I am using Resharper. I disabled it and noticed the behavior persists so looks like it's not Resharper related.

I have no idea what VS is doing with this huge amount of reads. All I can think of is it's probably related to the size of the solution and maybe it's reorganizing its data structures, reading caches from files...? What's strange is it's not doing any writes during the reads.

Anyone knows what it might be doing?

At least it forces me to take a break from coding!

Comment: What about NuGet? you have that on?

Comment: [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will let you see exactly what it's reading.  This tool helps me every time I do Windows development.

Comment: @LaceCard This is more of a http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx process monitor kind of task but yes.

Comment: I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7032551/10396) - it turned out to be the [Refactor! plugin](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/refactor_pro.xml)

Comment: @Meirion I have NuGet. What does it's On mean?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich as in you have NuGet active on your current project. Its not exactly the most stable of tools... just something to rule out.

Comment: @Meirion NuGet is installed in VS but not used in the project so I won't say it's active. I don't believe NuGet does anything unless you instruct to.

Comment: @LaceCard ProcessExplorer shows devenv.exe doing the reads. I have two processes under it which aren't doing any reads. How are you using ProcessExplorer to know what is doing all the reads. Do far I am not getting more than what the Task manager is already showing me.