# Store a string and a byte in a single int value

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm having trouble finding a solution for this. I need a method to store a string and a byte in a single int value. A hash is not good for this since the method should allow en- and decoding. Any hints would be appreciated, couldn't find a suitable algorithm.

Regards

Leo Tietz

Comment: Here are a few things that you may consider to add to your question: how long is your string? how big can your integer be? Do you want both of them at the same time /or/ at different times?

Comment: I'm really curious what the use case is here, especially in light of the fact that an int only gives you 4 bytes to work with.  What in the world has caused you to need to do this?

Comment: You need to describe your strings in greater detail.  This sounds like some kind of logging functionality.  If so there's a bounded number of predetermined strings that need encoding, and you might try my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864223/how-can-i-do-printf-style-debugging-over-a-slow-can-bus-with-constant-strings/17868083#17868083).  If not provide more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `int` has 32 bits. The byte will take 8 bits. That leaves you 24 bits to play with - enough for one and a half `char` values, uncompressed.

Unless you *really* only need to store single character strings, or you have a restricted range of characters that you need to represent, you need to revisit your requirements - it sounds like you're fundamentally going to have a problem with the amount of information you're trying to encode in a single `int`.

Answer (score 5):

An int can only store 4 bytes.  So if you have an ASCII String up to 3 bytes long you can store it like this

```
String s = ...
byte b = ...
int num = (s.charAt(0) << 24) + (s.charAt(1) << 16) 
        + (s.charAt(2) << 8) + (byte & 0xFF);
```

No amount of encoding will allow you to store more than 32-bits of information in an `int` no matter how you encoding it.  You could use a `long` which stores 64-bits and if you assume 7 bits for each char you can store 8 chars and a byte in total.